# Why not "eminentissimus" and "reverendissimus"?

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, case

When they announce a new pope the "Habemus Papam" text says "eminentissimum ac reverendissimum Dominum, Dominum 
Why is it? Why isn't "eminentissimus ac reverendissimus dominus ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just to make a better-tailored answer, are you familiar with declensions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say it's the same reason you see *papam* instead of *papa* above. That is, the whole thing is the direct object of *habēmus*.

In other words, the meaning is "we have a Pope, [we have a] most eminent and reverend…" and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The most important idea is already said by Draconis, but...

In case you are not familiar with *declensions*, nouns, adjectives and some pronouns in Latin change their ending depending on their grammatical function, in an analogous way as verbs in English end in -ed to signify they are in past tense.

In the example you give—**Papam** and **dominum**—, the -m ending means they are in the *accusative case*, i.e., they are objects to the verb, **habemus**. What do we have?—A Pope, Mr. Jorge Mario Card. Bergoglio. **Eminentissimum** and **reverendissimum** are adjectives modifying **dominum**, and hence must agree (they are also in accusative case)